# Discrepancy between Rubular regex and Rails regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want to validate U.S. phone numbers. On [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/m90FTkUxvv), the regex:

```
/^\(?([2-9][0-8][0-9])\)?[-.●]?([2-9][0-9]{2})[-.●]?([0-9]{4})$/
```

does not match the string:

```
'6463976583!'
```

as I expect. However, my Rails validator that uses the regex:

```
validates :phone, presence: true, format: {with: /^\(?([2-9][0-8][0-9])\)?[-.●]?([2-9][0-9]{2})[-.●]?([0-9]{4})$/}
```

seems to allow the same string.

Any thoughts as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: If you wish to go further than simply checking to see if the format is correct you might have a look at [this gem](https://github.com/daddyz/phonelib). If you don't need that there may be simpler gems that suit your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
pry(main)> '6463976583!'[/^\(?([2-9][0-8][0-9])\)?[-.]?([2-9][0-9]{2})[-.]?([0-9]{4})$/]?([0-9]{4})$/]
=> nil
pry(main)> '6463976583'[/^\(?([2-9][0-8][0-9])\)?[-.]?([2-9][0-9]{2})[-.]?([0-9]{4})$/]
=> "6463976583"
```

Perhaps try \A and \Z for your ActiveRecord validation: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of

The documentation mentions it matches start and end of a string versus start and end of a line. I believe that Rails or Rubocop one, throws warnings if you don't use ^ and $ instead of \A or \Z

If you can't get the Rails validator to work, you can create a custom validator method and call your regex there